# How do I store an access token for an external API in an ASP.NET Core server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, storage

I have a `ASP.NET Core 3.1` web server that, among other things, acts as a middleman between a front end Angular application and an external `API` service. It is supposed to make requests for data from the API service, which it will then deliver to the front end. To make requests to this API, it needs an `OAuth 2` access token. To be clear, it is the server that authenticates itself to access data available under a public license, and not specific to individual users on my server.

I currently have it planned out to use two typed `HttpClient` classes (based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1)) and one Controller to expose endpoints. One typed HttpClient would have a method for authenticating the server and retrieving an access token to return, using a client secret the server knows. The other client would provide methods for retrieving specific data from the external API, using the access token retrieved by the first client. Finally, the Controller would use the second `HttpClient` to get data to return on its endpoints.

What eludes me is how to manage the access token provided by the first `HttpClient`. I imagine it would be best to only retrieve it when it's needed, and then store it until it runs out, and then request a new one. How do I do this, or some alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an API client class which authenticates using your access client, then stores the access token, then use this class to make your API calls

```
public class ApiAccessClient
{

    public ApiAccessClient(string clientSecret)
    {
        ClientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

    public async Task Authenticate()
    {
        // Authentication code
        var response = await AuthClient.GetAsync(ClientSecret);
        AccessToken = "Access_Token";
    }

    public string MakeApiCall()
    {
        // Use access token
        return null;
    }

    private readonly string ClientSecret;

    private string AccessToken;

    private static HttpClient AuthClient;

    private static HttpClient AccessClient;

}
```

Note the HTTP clients are static so that connections are reused, read more: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a reasonable way to do it. I would note though that since `ASP.NET Core 2.1` the premise of that article is wrong if one is already using Core's provided `HttpClientFactory`, either directly or through dependency injection on typed clients, as I do. See https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore.